# Half of anaconda3 has py27 build path

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

While trying to install a particular package using conda, I didn't notice how many packages were going to be downgraded and foolishly gave the go-ahead. For the most part, the version numbers weren't downgraded, but they downgraded from a `py37` build channel to a `py27` build channel. Running `conda list` now gives me lines with a mix of py27 and py37:

```
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            5.2.4                    py27_0  
jupyter_console           5.2.0                    py27_1  
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py27_0  
jupyterlab                0.35.3                   py37_0
```

I can't remember what it looked like before, but I don't believe I had this garbled mess of python2 and python3, as I haven't built anything with python2 into my conda. Running `conda update --all` doesn't resolve this, as I believe it only checks the version and not the build path. How can I change everything back to python3 and ideally remove all traces of python2?

**Edit:**
The line in particular that caused this was `conda install -c menpo vtk=7` when trying to install [DAETools](http://daetools.com/docs/getting_daetools.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to fix this should be to explicitly install python=3, i.e.:

```
conda install python=3
```

possibly this will want to remove vtk again, but when I specified python=3, I got a version of vtk=7 build with python 3.5 from the same channel you used, i.e. there is a python 3 version available.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to revert your anaconda distribution back to 'factory settings' by executing `conda update conda`, followed by `conda install anaconda`. Afterwards all your package versions should be the same as the ones that you would have after a fresh installation of the (latest) full Anaconda distribution.